# Generate a group for each item in collection UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

i want to generate a Group for each item in my collection, the main idea is to fix the header of each item like Instagram in android.

I have my collection in this way:

```
List<Selfie> selfiesBag = new List<Selfie>();
```

and i display it in a `listview` with `datatemplates`.

How can i make to fix to top, when scroll a "part" of my `DataTemplate` item when scrolling?

When you scroll using Instagram for android, the "Header" of each picture is fixed to top until you scroll to the new picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please test the following procedure:

1/ Add a CollectionViewSource to your page ressources, for example :

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="CvsGroupedById" IsSourceGrouped="True"/>
```

2/ Create a query and assign it to your CVS, for example :

```
var query = from concert in DefaultViewModel.Concerts group concert by concert.Id into grp orderby grp.Key select grp;
CvsGroupedById.Source = query;
```

-> concert.Id should be unique if you want to create a group for each item

3/ Set your ListView.

```
MasterListEvents.ItemsSource = CvsGroupedById.View;
```

- optional - Change your ListView.GroupStyle to update the header of each section.